# Have some values available before accessing a singleton the first time or how to initialize object in singleton

Tags: c#, initialization, singleton

This is my current singleton:

```
public sealed class DataCollection
{
    // creating singleton instance (http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)
    private static readonly Lazy<DataCollection> lazy = new Lazy<DataCollection>(() => new DataCollection());

    public User currentUser { get; set; }

    public Filter currentFilter { get; set; }

    // fully laziness
    public static DataCollection Instance {
        get{
            return lazy.Value;
        }
    }

    private DataCollection ()
    {
    }
}
```

In my `Filter` object I have the following:

```
public class Filter
{
    public bool newEntries { get; set; }
    public List<PerfLoc> costCentres { get; set; }

    public Filter ()
    {
        newEntries = false;
        costCentres = new List<PerfLoc> ();
        read ();
    }

    public void read(){
        // do some initialization here (e.g. read some stored values in)
    }
}
```

Now I want to access the `Filter` like this:

```
globalData = DataCollection.Instance;
bool new = globalData.currentFilter.newEntries;
```

But here the `Filter` object isn't initialized and therefore null. I could create a new filter object and set it and then access it but it would be best if the initialization is done in the `Singleton` instance.

So I thought about an initialization like this:

```
private DataCollection ()
{
    currentFilter = new Filter();
}
```

Is this the correct way without compromising the singleton pattern? There should be a value available before accessing the `Filter` for the first time. Later I thought to create a new `Filter` object and set it with my `globalData` instance.

Comment: You shouldn't probably use a singleton if your `currentFilter` might change. Otherwise it's fine to set it in the private constructor.

Comment: @aush: I need the `currentFilter` at multiple places. Therefore I thought to use the Singleton pattern. Do you think it would be better to create my own getter and make the setter private of `currentFilter`? So that I always have one object and never creates another one temporarily?

Comment: What instead of the singleton should I use? A static class, delegates or simply passing values?

Comment: Yes, if you're not going to change a value of the `currentFilter` during a lifetime of your `DataCollection` then you simply put a private setter and make an assignment in the private constructor. As for your second question, singleton is not a bad pattern, you just have to have a clear reason why you need it.

Comment: OK I think I haven't expressed me correctly. The `currentFilter` properties does change. The reason why I use the singleton pattern is that I need those values at multiple places. Currently I'm using it with the initialization in the private constructor. And I asked the question with the private setter because I wanted to avoid creating a temporary `Filter` object. Because I made the initialization in the singleton I now can use `globalData.currentFilter.newEntries = true` and doesn't need my temporary object anymore.

Comment: Ok, I see. I don't think that your reason to use a singleton is valid. Your singleton is just a static variable in this case. If I were you I would definitely create on abstraction over the `DataCollection` layer and inject a dependency on it to the types which need this dependency.

Comment: @aush: I don't quite get your advice. Could you post a link or something like that where this is explained in more detail? Perhaps I go away from the singleton and use a `Filter` instance with static fields and methods.

Comment: There is a lot of information about it. Just google something like "why service locator is bad" and "why static variable is bad". Also google "inversion of control" and "dependency injection" to learn about good practices.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct way without compromising the singleton pattern?

Yes, singleton only has to do with having a single instance and the access of that instance, create it any way you like.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern
>   that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is
>   useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across
>   the system. The concept is sometimes generalized to systems that
>   operate more efficiently when only one object exists, or that restrict
>   the instantiation to a certain number of objects. The term comes from
>   the mathematical concept of a singleton.
>
> There is criticism of the use of the singleton pattern, as some
>   consider it an anti-pattern, judging that it is overused, introduces
>   unnecessary restrictions in situations where a sole instance of a
>   class is not actually required, and introduces global state into an
>   application.

Have a look at that article and reason whether or not the singleton pattern is the correct choice for you.